# How to identify active vs inactive ISINs?

Tags: programming, market-data, ticker-mapping

**Background**

I understand that through the work of [ANNA](https://www.anna-web.org/standards/lei/) and [GLEIF](https://www.gleif.org/en/lei-data/lei-mapping/download-isin-to-lei-relationship-files), the relationships between ISINs and their respective LEI (Legal Entity Identifier) are now more accessible.

**GLEIF API Lookup**

To lookup the ISINs that pertain to an LEI, one can use the [GLEIF API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7679680/SVYrrxuU?version=latest), for example for Apple, Inc.:

https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394/isins

which returns some 990 ISINs.

Whilst I appreciate that ISINs are specific to financial instrument types (shares, bonds etc) and that there may be many "issues" of each I'm struggling to work out how to determine the "active" ISIN for a certain instrument.

Certainly, I'm unable to establish this from the GLIEF API as it only returns the ISIN identifiers themselves (reasonably perhaps).

Following the Apple example further, from other sources I "know" its active shares ISIN is: US0378331005

**ISIN Lookup**

Consulting the ISIN database corroborates the same:

[https://www.isin.net/isin-directory/isin-profile/?isin=US0378331005](https://www.isin.net/isin-directory/?search=US0378331005)

Further, when I query the ISIN database for other ISINs (from the GLEIF response), I typically receive a "No results found" e.g. https://www.isin.net/isin-directory/?search=US03785CD961.

**Questions**

1. Am I correct in assuming that the "No results found" is synonymous with an "inactive" ISIN? I'm not an expert (at any level) in the share issue process, but I understand that new issues may replace existing issues, sometimes requiring new ISINs depending on the nature of the issue.
2. Is there any way to determine the active ISIN? Perhaps from a separate ISIN source?

Note: I have looked at the ANNA data but this does not indicate the ISIN status as far as I can see.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi: algoseek sells what is called their security master file. It contains enough information in it to be able to determine  if the ISIN is active. I bought it from algoseek when I bought data from them but maybe you can buy it stand-alone ? I'm not sure but it's worth contacting them.

Comment: mark, thanks for this. I've had a quick look and there's definitely reference to the status if the ISIN (listed or delisted) so I think if nothing else that's the terms I'm looking for. The algoseek data appears to be mainly US focused though, and I'd prefer a non-paid for option if possible.

Comment: hmmm - https://www.isin.org/education/ refers to ISIN status as "active" or "inactive" perhaps in response to a company "delisting". Semantics perhaps...

Comment: paulkmoore: my mistake and apologies. you are correct that algoseek is U.S based. I forgot about that issue because I'm totally focused on U.S these days. There may be other free options but I don't know one.  good luck.